# Nodejs . Getting [object,Object] when fs.writeFileSync

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse

I am reading a csv file, then writing another in the format I need.  console.log shows the data i need but the file I create shows [object, Object] for each line.

I am not sure why the console.log shows the correct data but the file does not. I've read over the Node documentation but I cannot figure this out. Any information you can provide is appreciated.

[this is what console.log shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btQlG.png)

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var parse = require('csv-parse');

//read file
var inputFile = 'EXAMPLE_UPSdailyShipment.csv';

fs.createReadStream('EXAMPLE_UPSdailyShipment.csv', "utf8", function read(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  content = data;
});

var arr = [];

//data for new file
var parser = parse({
  delimiter: ","
}, function(err, data) {

  data.forEach(function(column) {
    // create line object, data from parsed fields, PackageReference1 is order#
    var line = {
      "BuyerCompanyName": " ",
      "OrderNumber": column[8],
      "ShipperName": "UPS",
      "TrackingNumber": column[9],
      "DateShipped": column[0],
      "ShipmentCost": column[2],
    };
    arr.push(line);
  });
  console.log(arr);
  fs.writeFileSync("newtemp3.csv", arr, 'utf8');
  console.log("file read and new file created")
});

fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to stringify the data first:

```
fs.writeFileSync("newtemp3.csv", JSON.stringify(arr), 'utf8');
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.